# Winapi LoadBitmap() is not loading images from my resources

Tags: winapi, bitmap, hbitmap, gdi

In my .rc file I have add line:

```
IMG BITMAP "myIMG.bmp" //add to resources
```

Prototype in .cpp file:

```
HBITMAP     Image;
```

after `ShowWindow()` I load it in to memory with:

```
Image=LoadBitmap(hInstance,"IMG");
```

On `WM_CREATE:` I load it on to the screen and clear it out:

```
HDC GetDC (hdc);    
HDC newhdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);   
SelectObject(newhdc,Image);
BitBlt(hdc,30,70,491,302,newhdc,0,0,SRCCOPY);
DeleteDC(newhdc);
DeleteObject(Image);
ReleaseDC(hwnd,hdc);
```

Thanks to @BeneGal question (founded here) I have created a MB that tells if the img is not loaded:

```
if(Image == NULL) {
MessageBox(NULL, "NO IMAGE LOADED!", "Error!",  MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
}
```

When I paste the above code right after `ShowWindow()` the MB don't appear, when I paste it on `WM_CREATE:` it appears. Don't know why.

edit: Well actually I forgot to tell that image does not appear on my window and that is the main problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your bitmap in WM_CREATE use it in WM_PAINT. Keep track of return objects by SelectObject and don't delete object which are still selected in HDC. Do something like that http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/bitmaps.html

Comment: Well that was the trick :) thank you. I have also deleted: `HDC GetDC (hdc);` `DeleteObject(Image);` `ReleaseDC(hwnd,hdc);` and added `GetObject()` function so I can get image size :)